# Find out who/what is calling a script (cron)

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, cron

I was having a problem recently where somebody's cron job was calling a script that sent an alert to me when it was run. I wanted to find out whose job it was and which server it was running on.

The problem has been resolved by someone else, but I was wondering what I could have done to find out which host/username the job is being run from. One thing I could think of was to edit the script (Perl) and use Sys::Hostname. Anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: You have the email, check the email header

Comment: @ajreal, he didn't say the alert was delivered by email.

Comment: my bad, my originally meant if the alert is via email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do that unless you use mail to send out the alerts. Mails contain the host name in the header, so you can at least see where it came from (user and host). The time stamp should then help to locate the cron job.

For all other forms of alerts (SMS, pager, etc), you should make it a policy to include the user and hostname in the message.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you can get the hostname with [Sys::Hostname](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys%3a%3aHostname).  You can also get the username with `getpwuid($<)`:

```
use Sys::Hostname;

my $info = getpwuid($<) . '@' . hostname;

print "$info\n"; # prints user@host
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add to your script: `` print `env|sort`; ``  -- that would reveal the USERNAME or LOGNAME.  If you don't want to mess with the output of your program, log it to a file:

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
open my $log, '>>', 'logfile' or die "can't append to logfile: $!\n";
print $log strftime(%Y-%m-%d %T", localtime), " - starting $0\n";
print $log `env|sort`;
close $log;
```